# How to use blueimp jquery file upload in kohana?

Tags: php, kohana, jquery-file-upload

I would like to use blueimp jquery file upload with kohana framework, but can't implement it properly. I have controller with index action with upload handler initialization like this:

```
 class Controller_Ajax_Jfupload extends Controller_Ajax {

        public function action_index() {
            $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
        }

    }
```

UploadHandler.php is copied to /Controller folder. I created view with html given in example file. But is not working at all. I do not know where to put url pointing on my upload controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods: this is my Method

```
public function action_index() {
//no render the body of page : error json
        $this->auto_render=false; 
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
        require('UploadHandler.php');
        $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
    }
```

Don't forget this script in your page:

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>

    $(function() {
        'use strict';

        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: 'yourUrl' (in this case index)
        });

        // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:


        if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
            // Demo settings:

            $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
                url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
                disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                maxFileSize: 5000000,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
            });
            // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
            if ($.support.cors) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
                    type: 'HEAD'
                }).fail(function() {
                    $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                            .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                            new Date())
                            .appendTo('#fileupload');
                });
            }
        } else {

            // Load existing files:
            $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

            $.ajax({
                // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
                //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
                dataType: 'json',
                context: $('#fileupload')[0]

            }).always(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
            }).done(function(result) {
                alert('done')
                $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
                        .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
            });
        }

    });

</script>
```